# Trying to render JSON in HTML in Angular2

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I'm trying to render a returned JSON from the backend in to HTML `{{ object.x }}`, I'm using `BehaviourSubject` in my shared-service where I call the API endpoint of the list I'm trying to render.

```
public storesChanged = new BehaviorSubject([]);

public getStores(): void {
  this.retrieveResults().subscribe((results) => {
    this.storesChanged.next(results.Results)
      console.log('Name >> ', results.Results[0].Name) // this shows me the Name
  });
}
public retrieveResults(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('/api/Stores/Summary')
  .map(res => res.json())
}
```

using this service:

```
this.sharedService.storesChanged.subscribe((res) => {
  this.currentStore = res.find((x) => x.Id === this.storeId)
  // this returns the object based on the Id which should be able to use in my HTML
})
```

This is the object which I'm trying to render in HTML `{{ currentStore.Name }}` however it's returning an error `Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined`.

```
{
   'Id': 1,
   'Name': 'Eastleigh'
}
```

I'm quite confused why its returning `'Name' of undefined` when the property is in the object. Can someone point-out the cause.

Comment: `{{ currentSore.Name }}` -> `{{ currentStore.Name }}` you have a typo

Comment: Yeah sorry that's my own typo while typing this question

Comment: Did you try the elvis operator? `{{ currentStore?.Name }}`

Comment: @echonax what that worked, not sure what's the elvis operator though? Mind giving a small explanation?

Comment: Elvis operator guards against "property not found". If "name" doesn't exist on currentStore, it will stop trying to evaluate it (and any other props that follow it) saving you from horrible errors. This way when "name" is eventually available, you'll get what you expect.

Comment: @TimConsolazio so does that mean if `x.Name` isn't available yet when I change location it won't update the on the template `{{ currentStore?.Name}}`?.

Comment: No, it should just not attempt to resolve .Name until .Name is actually available. It should work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `currentStore` object is received asynchronously, you can use the "elvis" operator like this

```
{{ currentStore?.Name }}
```

"elvis" or safe navigation operator will check your object if it's null/undefined or not. And when it's defined, angular will try to access the property you have selected (Name).

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_navigation_operator

Comment: Thanks sounds like a handy operator to do a check.

Comment: @MrNew It really makes your life easier when you deal with async operations in angular2 :-)

Comment: Hi, just one more question about this I know its old. Now that its showing the storeName, somehow it doesn't always update the `{{ currentStore?.Name }}` sometimes I have to refresh the page for it to update.

Comment: @MrNew Hmm, can't say anything without seeing the use-case. Maybe you are getting an error in the console? Can you create a new question that elobarates the issue?

Comment: I created a new question about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818222/update-template-using-routerlink-in-angular2/41818486#41818486

Comment: I think I fixed it now :) but feel free too look at the question and correct me if I'm wrong. I edited the question with my fix.

Comment: @MrNew seems fine to me, glad you figured it out :-)