# update template using routerLink in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm having problem with my template not being updated when I move to another `store location`. (e.g) Default is `Eastleigh` and if I move to `USA` it will change to `USA` but when I go to somewhere else it stuck to `USA`.

I have to refresh the page so that the template would update `Collection Store - {{}}` which shouldn't be the case.

In my template html I have this.

```
<span> Collection Store - {{ currentStore?.Name }}</span>
```

locations are being returned from the back end - using this service:

```
public storesChanged = new BehaviorSubject([]);

public getStores(): void {
  this.retrieveResults().subscribe((results) => {
    this.storesChanged.next(results.Results)
      console.log('Name >> ', results.Results[0].Name) // this shows me the Name
  });
}
public retrieveResults(): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get('/api/Stores/Summary')
  .map(res => res.json())
}
```

Component -

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.storeId = +params['storeId'];
      this.storeLocation = params['storeLocation'];
      if (!this.storeId) {
        this.storeId = DEFAULT_ORIGIN_ID;
      }
    })

    this.sharedService.storesChanged.subscribe((res) => {
      this.currentStore = res.find((x) => x.Id === this.storeId);
      console.log('Change Location >> ', this.currentStore)
    })
  }
```

This is how I render the dropdown menu urls,

```
<li *ngFor="let store of sourceSites | slice:1" [class.active-location]="storeId === store.Id"><a id="{{store.Name}}" [routerLink]="['/order-screen/store/' + store.Id + '/' +store.Name]">{{ store.Name}}</a></li>
```

Can someone point out why the template where I render `currentStore?.Name` is not always updating? I don't want to refresh the page every time I change to select a different url/location.

**Fixed**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.routeSub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
          this.storeId = +params['storeId'];
          this.storeLocation = params['storeLocation'];
          if (!this.storeId) {
            this.storeId = DEFAULT_ORIGIN_ID;
          }
          this.sharedService.storesChanged.subscribe((res) => {
            this.currentStore = res.find((x) => x.Id === this.storeId);
            console.log('Change Location >> ', this.currentStore)
          })
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If those urls is used the same component. You can subscribe the url params change.
e.g.

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class DemoPage {
    constructor(private _route: ActivatedRoute) { }
    ngOnInit() {
            this._route.params.forEach(params => {
                    let storeId= params["storeId"];
                    this.getStoreInfo(storeId);
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm already subscribed to it, sorry forgot to mention it above. I've added the code in my question.

Comment: I think I've fixed it now, my `storeChanged` service is outside the `params.subscribe` when it should be inside.